# RegEx for capturing digits in a string

Tags: c#, regex, regex-lookarounds, regex-group, uipath

I'm looking to extract only the numbers after this "=»", but i keep having some other text too:

#### Regex code:

```
[^»]*[\d{1,}]$
```

#### Input

```
> login as: LOGIN SERVER@00.00.00.000's password: Last login: Thu May 23
> 15:51:49 2019 from 00.00.00.000 CREER AUTANT DE REPERTOIRES SOUS
> /NAME/NAME/NAME QU'IL Y A DE COMMERCANTS GERES. LE NOM DOIT ETRE LE NO
> DE COMMERCANT. CREER ENSUITE SOUS CHACUN D'EUX UN REPERTOIRE NAME/
> <SERVER>ps -fu NAME | grep exe | echo «resultat=»`wc -l` «resultat=»14
> <SERVER>
```

How do I solve this problem?

Comment: Please post your code directly in your question instead of a link. Links go stale and make it so questions are useless for people that come across the question in the future.

Comment: Here i posted it now, i used a link before...

Comment: `[^»]*([\d{1,}])` returns `14` for your post...

Comment: @Michael no it doesn't, it returns other informations too...

Answer (score 5):

Your expression is pretty close. We might just want to have `=»` as a left boundary, then collect our digits with a `([0-9]+)` and that would likely work:

```
=»([0-9]+)
```

[image]

#### RegEx

If this expression wasn't desired, it can be modified or changed in [regex101.com](https://regex101.com/r/VmP3l9/1/).

#### RegEx Circuit

[jex.im](https://jex.im/regulex/#!flags=&re=%5E(a%7Cb)*%3F%24) visualizes regular expressions:

[image]

#### Test

```
using System;
using System.Text.RegularExpressions;

public class Example
{
    public static void Main()
    {
        string pattern = @"=»([0-9]+)";
        string input = @"> login as: LOGIN SERVER@00.00.00.000's password: Last login: Thu May 23
> 15:51:49 2019 from 00.00.00.000 CREER AUTANT DE REPERTOIRES SOUS
> /NAME/NAME/NAME QU'IL Y A DE COMMERCANTS GERES. LE NOM DOIT ETRE LE NO
> DE COMMERCANT. CREER ENSUITE SOUS CHACUN D'EUX UN REPERTOIRE NAME/
> <SERVER>ps -fu NAME | grep exe | echo «resultat=»`wc -l` «resultat=»14
> <SERVER>";
        RegexOptions options = RegexOptions.Multiline;

        foreach (Match m in Regex.Matches(input, pattern, options))
        {
            Console.WriteLine("'{0}' found at index {1}.", m.Value, m.Index);
        }
    }
}
```

#### Demo

```js
const regex = /=»([0-9]+)/gm;
const str = `> login as: LOGIN SERVER@00.00.00.000's password: Last login: Thu May 23
> 15:51:49 2019 from 00.00.00.000 CREER AUTANT DE REPERTOIRES SOUS
> /NAME/NAME/NAME QU'IL Y A DE COMMERCANTS GERES. LE NOM DOIT ETRE LE NO
> DE COMMERCANT. CREER ENSUITE SOUS CHACUN D'EUX UN REPERTOIRE NAME/
> <SERVER>ps -fu NAME | grep exe | echo «resultat=»\`wc -l\` «resultat=»14
> <SERVER>`;
let m;

while ((m = regex.exec(str)) !== null) {
    // This is necessary to avoid infinite loops with zero-width matches
    if (m.index === regex.lastIndex) {
        regex.lastIndex++;
    }
    
    // The result can be accessed through the `m`-variable.
    m.forEach((match, groupIndex) => {
        console.log(`Found match, group ${groupIndex}: ${match}`);
    });
}
```

Comment: this returns two values, i need only 14  Full match=»14
Group 1. 14

Comment: @mz3bel You can just use c# to extract `14` from `=»14`.

Answer (score 0):

Characters in square brackets mean “one of these characters”, so it's ? or » followed by a digit or { , 1 , , or } .

Positive lookbehind is the most useful here (match something that comes after X .)

> (?<=something)thingIWantToMatch

So:

> (?<=»)\d+

One or more digits preceded by a » , but don’t capture the »